# XML сериализация с помощью DataContractSerializer затрагивает игнорируемые поля

Tags: xml, сериализация

Использую в проекте 3 вида сериализации: json, yaml и xml.
Первые 2 отлично работают с таким классом:

```
    [DataContract]
    public class FileMetaInfo
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Hash { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public long Size { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Author { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime CreationDateTime { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int DownloadsCount { get; set; }

        public int FileMetaInfoId { get; set; }
        public int StorageId { get; set; }
        public virtual Storage Storage { get; set; }

        public FileMetaInfo() { }
    }
```

Они не трогают последние 3 свойства как и положено. А xml пытается в любом случае лезть и туда и на выходе - exception

Вот код XML сериализации:

```
public void Serialize<T>(T source, string path)
        {
            using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(path))
            {
                using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(file))
                {
                    DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
                    serializer.WriteObject(writer, source);
                }               
            }
        }
```

[IgnoreDataMemberAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute.aspx) не предлагать, он в данном случае не нужен и не работает

Ошибки, начиная с верхнего уровня:

> 1. "There was an error reflecting type 'GodelMastery.FileStorage.Data.Models.FileMetaInfo[]'."
> 2. "There was an error reflecting type 'GodelMastery.FileStorage.Data.Models.FileMetaInfo'."
> 3. "There was an error reflecting property 'Storage'."
> 4. "There was an error reflecting type 'GodelMastery.FileStorage.Data.Models.Storage'."
> 5. "Cannot serialize member 'GodelMastery.FileStorage.Data.Models.Storage.Files' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[GodelMastery.FileStorage.Data.Models.FileMetaInfo, GodelMastery.FileStorage.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]', see inner exception for more details."
> 6. "Cannot serialize member GodelMastery.FileStorage.Data.Models.Storage.Files of type System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[GodelMastery.FileStorage.Data.Models.FileMetaInfo, GodelMastery.FileStorage.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] because it is an interface."

По ошибкам видно, что он лезет в Storage

Comment: Какой exception? Приведите его текст. И у меня ваш код работает, сериализуются только свойства, помеченные `DataMember`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, [скриншот ошибки](https://prnt.sc/jj09uj)

Comment: Комментарии мало кто читает. Почти никто не увидит скриншот. Поэтому отредактируйте вопрос, добавив в него текст исключения. Причём имеенно в виде _текста_, а не _скриншота_.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, исправил

Comment: Любопытно. Хоть решение уже найдено, но можно попробовать использовать `XmlSerializer`. Так как `DataContractSerializer` предназначен в основном для использования в составе WCF.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему используя резолвер:

```
DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer
    (typeof(T), 
    new DataContractSerializerSettings 
    {
        DataContractResolver = new ProxyDataContractResolver()
    });
```